# Gatsby page generation not filtering out slug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to generate Gatsby pages based on data in my CMS (Sanity).

I have created three pages in my CMS under the umbrella term "Second page", I use createPage in gatsby-node to generetate pages with the correct slugs.

All the pages are generated according to their slug from the CMS, but in my template component I cannot filter out data. I get the result for all three pages when I only need the result for the one page that matches the slug. My console.log in secondPage.js shows three arrays corresponding to the three items in my CMS

gatsby-node.js

```
// Create pages for docs
exports.createPages = ({ actions, graphql }) => {
  const path = require(`path`);
  const { createPage } = actions;
  //const docTemplate = path.resolve("src/templates/docTemplate.js");
  const secondPageTemplate = path.resolve("src/templates/secondPage.js");

  return graphql(`
    {

      allSanitySecondPage {
        edges {
          node {
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `).then((result) => {
    if (result.errors) {
      Promise.reject(result.errors);
    }

    result.data.allSanitySecondPage.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
      createPage({
        path: node.slug,
        component: secondPageTemplate,
        context: {
          slug: node.slug,
        },
      });
    });
  });
};
```

secondPage.js (template)

```
import React from "react";
import { graphql } from "gatsby";
import Layout from "../components/layout";

const BlockContent = require("@sanity/block-content-to-react");

const secondPage = ({ data }) => {
  // const pageData = data.sanitySecondPage.edges.node;
  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>Hello from the second page!</h1>
      {console.log(data.sanitySecondPage)}

      {/* <BlockContent blocks={pageData._rawBlockContent} /> */}
    </Layout>
  );
};

export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    sanitySecondPage(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      _rawBlockContent
    }
  }
`;

export default secondPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that all I needed was to write a stack overflow post to solve my own issue. Everything was correct, I miss understood the return of block content, it was supposed to be three array elements.